# C++ interactive command line prompt without waiting for a newline character

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a way to process command line input before seeing the newline character? I'm thinking of making a program that supports autocomplete (like the ones found in search engines or iOS keyboard).

To be more specific, my program will prompt for user input when started, and for each character input, I would like to output something ***BEFORE*** the newline character(or EOF) is input.

The following code snippet is what I have tried:

```
int main(){
    char ch; 
    while ( (ch = cin.get()) != cin.eof() )
    {       
        cout << ch << flush;
    }   
}
```

expected: for each character input, output that character.

actual: does not output anything UNTIL the program sees an eof.

Comment: Because "c" tag was given: You can also read from stdin with read(). And you can send an ETX (e.g. Ctrl-D). But I guess what you want is NOT reading from stdin but e.g. keystrokes from terminal.

Comment: `cin.eof()` returns a boolean. You probably mean the `EOF` macro or `std::char_traits<char>::eof()`.

Comment: No.  There is no standard way to read a single character from a console.

Comment: This can be done, but it is not standard so you'll want to tag your question with the system you want to support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Unix-like system, you can achieve this by changing the terminal to **non-canonical** input mode. Terminal supports **canonical input** which gathers the entire line for editing until the end of line character or `Ctrl-D` is pressed. As a result, the application often sees whole line on the read() system calls. On the other hand, **non-canonical** input does no line buffering; the input characters are made available to the program as soon as they are typed.

Here is a Linux C/C++ example of how to set `-icanon` flag (**non-canonical**) programmatically.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    struct termios old_tio, new_tio;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &old_tio);
    new_tio = old_tio;
    new_tio.c_lflag &= (~ICANON);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &new_tio);
    char c;
    while (fread(&c, 1, 1, stdin))
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: never knew there existed such a thing! Thanks Amos for your kind explanation and the example code!!! worked like a charm!

Comment: Do you have to reset the terminal to canonical mode after the app completes? i.e. does the change apply to this process, or to the terminal

Comment: @TSG It will affect the related terminal. So the best practice would be reset terminal to some sane default before exiting.